# Matplotlib x-ticks goes from Jan-Jan instead of Jan-Dec

Tags: python, pandas, date, matplotlib

I have daily weather data from Jan 1 - Dec 31 for a year. I'm plotting this daily data and want my x-ticks to be monthly intervals. But when I plot it, the x-tick goes from Jan - Jan instead of Jan-Dec. How do I get rid of the last x-tick that has Jan and limit it till December.

If I set the xlim from Jan to Dec the graph covers the entire axes. I want a bit of a gap from where the lines start and ends.

Date is in the format YYYY-MM-DD

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime

plt.figure()
plt.plot(minmax2014['Date'], minmax2014['min'], color='r', label='Record High')
plt.plot(minmax2014['Date'], minmax2014['max'], color='b', label='Record Low')

plt.legend(loc=2)

d=minmax2014['Date'].values
plt.gca().fill_between(d, minmax2014['max'], minmax2014['min'], facecolor='yellow', alpha=0.3)

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b'))
```

[image: the Graph with xticks]

Comment: is it 100% confirmed that there is no data for January in another year? That will change the answer

Comment: The ticks here are at, for example `Dec 01`. You still need to show `Dec 02,..., Dec 31`. As a matter of fact, `Dec 31` is so close to `Jan 01` of the next year so it makes sense having another tick `Jan`, (think `1.99` and `2` with integer ticks)

Comment: Yes, it is confirmed that there is no data for Jan of another year.

Is there a way to change the xtick for months at about 15th of every month rather than at the 1st of the month? I'd rather not have the new Jan xtick as the data is for a single year. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just set the xlimit, or the ticks.  You could fo course make your own locator, but that seems overkill for what you are truing to do.

Note I've used `datetime64` here, but you could easily just use `datetime`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 1, constrained_layout=True)
dates = np.arange('2000-01-01T01:00:00', '2000-12-31T23:00:00',
                  dtype='datetime64[h]')
y = np.random.randn(len(dates))
for a in ax:
    a.plot(dates, y)

ax[1].set_xlim(np.datetime64('1999-12-31T23:59:59'), np.datetime64('2000-12-31T23:00:00'))


ticks = [np.datetime64('2000-%02d-01'%month) for month in range(1, 13)]
ax[2].set_xticks(ticks)
ax[2].xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b'))

for a in ax[:-1]:
    a.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
    a.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b'))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I was trying to avoid starting and ending at the axes, but it seems that this might be the only feasible way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in your comment, yes, we can move the ticks to the middle of the month:

```
minmax2014 = pd.DataFrame({
    'min': np.random.uniform(0,10,365),
    'max': np.random.uniform(90,100,365),
    'Date':pd.date_range('2014-01-01', '2014-12-31', freq='D')
}, )
plt.figure()
plt.plot(minmax2014['Date'], minmax2014['min'], color='r', label='Record High')
plt.plot(minmax2014['Date'], minmax2014['max'], color='b', label='Record Low')

plt.legend(loc=2)

d=minmax2014['Date'].values
plt.gca().fill_between(d, minmax2014['max'], minmax2014['min'], facecolor='yellow', alpha=0.3)

# new ticks at 15th of months
ticks = pd.date_range('2014-01-01', '2014-12-31', freq='MS') + pd.Timedelta(days=14)

# set ticks
plt.xticks(ticks)

# set tick names
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b'))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I'd *really* *really* advise against not moving the ticks to the middle of the month, unless you just have one data point per month.  No reasonable person would look at the plot and say that the "Jan" marker was Jan 15th.

Comment: I'd rather leaving the `Jan` as well. But OP asked to move the ticks :-).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I now see why moving the tick would be a bad idea. But thank you, learnt something new about moving the x-ticks. Based on that, would we be able to have just 12 ticks instead of 13 so that the last Jan doesn't show up?(when the ticks are on the first of every month)