# xticks showing Jan-Jan when plotting pandas dataframe, but want Jan-Dec only

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have tried searching for an answer to my problem but cannot find one. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58137123/matplotlib-x-ticks-goes-from-jan-jan-instead-of-jan-dec) question is slightly different, and doesn't suit.

I want the xticks on my figure to run from Jan to Dec only, but in my case they are running from Jan to Jan. See below.

[image]

In each timeseries there are 365 points in each year from 01-01 to 12-31.

Code to reproduce this is below.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(365*4), index=pd.date_range("1/1/2000", periods=365*4))

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(365*4, 1), index=ts.index, columns=list("A"))
df['year'] = df.index.year
df['date'] = df.index.strftime('%m-%d')
df = df.set_index(['year', 'date']).A.unstack(-2)


fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 5))
df.plot(ax=axs)
axs.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
axs.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b'))
```

I have tried removing points in the timeseries e.g. `01-01` and `12-31`, but this does not help.

Any help removing the final Jan xtick would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option might be to just remove the last tick:

```
axs.set_xticks(axs.get_xticks()[:-1])
```

Output:

[image]